# How to add Highcharts low and high data series using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

I was trying to create a graph that represents the schedule of our Store using highcharts. With that, I use columnrange to a start and end time where the store is open.

But I'm stuck on how can I push those data using array and json.
Here's what I want to achieve. I made this mock-up with hard coded data;

```
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rds_a/Lscqugbp/3/

code:
    $(function () {

    window.chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'columnrange',
            inverted: false
        },

        title: {
            text: "Store Schedule"
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Yesterday','Today']
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 24,
            categories: ['01','02','03', '04','05', '06','07', '08', '09','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15','16','17', '18', '19','20', '21','22','23', '24'],
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                grouping: false
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Open',
            stack: 'OnSite',
            color: 'orange',
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                low: 7,
                high: 10
            },{
                x: 0,
                low: 11,
                high: 16
            },{
                x: 1,
                low: 6,
                high: 12
            },{
                x: 1,
                low: 17,
                high: 21
            }]
        },
            {
            name: 'Close',
            stack: 'OnSite',
            color: 'black',
            data: [
                {
                x: 0,
                low: 01,
                high: 07
            },{
                x: 0,
                low: 10,
                high: 11
            },
                ,{
                x: 0,
                low: 15,
                high: 24
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 1,
                high: 7
            },
            {
                x: 1,
                low: 12,
                high: 17
            },
                 {
                x: 1,
                low: 21,
                high: 24
            }]
                 }]

    });    
});
```

While here's what I'am currently have;

```
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/rds_a/9P5fC/485/

code:

 $(function () {
    var jdata = {
        "Open": {
        "y": [4,8],
        "name": "Open",
        "n": [0]
        },
        "Closed": {
        "y": [9,12],
        "name": "Closed",
        "n": [1]
        }
    };

    var seriesArr = [];
    $.each(jdata, function (key, data) {
        var series = {
            name: key,
            data: []
        };

        $.each(data.y, function (index, value) {
            series.data.push({
                y: value
            });
        });

        $.each(data.n, function (index, value) {
            series.data[index].n = value;
        });
        seriesArr.push(series);
    });

    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            inverted: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Store Schedule'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 24,
            categories: ['01','02','03', '04','05', '06','07', '08', '09','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15','16','17', '18', '19','20', '21','22','23', '24'],
            title: {
                text: 'Time'
            }
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

           plotOptions: {
            columnrange: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },

        series: seriesArr
    };


    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Thanks in advance to those who can give their inputs.

Comment: Could you tell what means: `"y": [4,8],` ? It's open/closed from 4:00 to 8:00? I guess it doesn't, because you also have: `"y": [5,9]`. Simple example, where first value is used as starting hour, and duration is set to one hour: http://jsfiddle.net/9P5fC/487/ (part: `high: value + 1`).

Comment: Hi Pawel Fus, thank you for paying attention on my question. I'am really stuck on this part and need someones help. "y": [4,8] means the range where the Store is Open and the other "y": [5,9] means when the store is Closed. My problem is how to set '4' as low and '8' as high using javascript. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to explain more. Does that mean that it is open from 4 until 8? Or do you mean it's open from 4-5 and 8-9?  Where does the 'jdata' come from? Do you build that, or are you stuck with how it comes to you?

Comment: I'd review the sample you did and it's pretty closed on what I want to achieve. I saw you add high = value + 1 just to show a value for 'high'. My question is how can I put the value of high inside "y"? Really sorry for disturbing you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello jlbriggs. Yes, from my example.. The store is Open from 4 until 8 AND   it is closed form 5 until 9. I got this method from a lot of research but my problem is how could I fetch low and high from 'jdata'. Currently you can see that I can just get 1 data at a time. Sorry for confusing you, Thank you very much for helping me guys.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this doesn't make much sense for me... how shop can be opened from 04:00 to 08:00 and at the same time closed from 05:00 to 09:00 ? I'm very curious.

Comment: I think my data samples confused you guys. I just saw today that it was wrong. It should be Open from 04:00 to 08:00 AND Closed from 09:00 to 12:00.. Really sorry for the confusion. Looking forward for your help, Thank you!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9P5fC/489/ ?

Comment: Ohh!! You got it Pawel Fus. That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much!